# Iterate over json to add marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm stuck on this problem. I think the answer is quite simple but i don't find it...
I want to iterate over the json to add Marker on my map. How can i select value.lat or value.lng.
Thank you for you're help.

```
[{
id: "1",
lat: "48.901196",
lng: "2.334080"
},
{
id: "2",
lat: "48.847008",
lng: "2.301430"
}]

 $.each(json, function (i, item) {
            $.each(item, function (key, value) {
                console.log(value.lat); //return undefined
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lng);

                 new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: value.id
                });

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
 $.each(json, function (i, item) {
     alert(item.lat);
......
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the inner `$.each` loop, and just grab the value from the `item`, which references the current object in the Array.

```
// ------------------------v------- this holds each object in the array
$.each(json, function (i, item) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng);

     new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: item.id
    });
});
```